# Where does it come $\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$

Tags: power-series

Where does it come $$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate the given sum termwise and you will get

$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[x^n\right]'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$$

Hence the first term of this sum equals zero we can let start the series at $n=1$ as well. Plugging in this change and applying an index shift afterwards leads to

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n}$$

Comment: +1 for the answer. Anyway, I've added an answer that I think it's easier to be understood.

Comment: @the_candyman Yes, you are right. Your answer is more comprehensive and honestly speaking indeed clearer to be understood. Therefore I upvoted your answer as well :)

Answer (score 3):

$(x^n)' = n x^{n-1}$, with care given to interchange of limits.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

I will **try** to give a **clearer answer**, but this is essentially the **same** as the one provided by **mrtaurho**.

---

Look at this:

$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \left[x^0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \left[1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = 0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}.$$

Now, let's pose $m = n-1$. It is clear that:

1. $m=0$ when $n = 1$;
2. $m=\infty$ when $n = \infty$;
3. $n = m + 1$.

Therefore:

$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)x^{m}.$$

At this point, you are free to **rename** $n = m$ (but this "$n$" is different from the "$n$" used at the very beginning!!! pay attention on this point!!!), thus obtaining the following:

$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n}.$$